# ¿Cómo obtener el presupuesto?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un sistema que entregar mañana y estoy trabado en varias cosas

Como multiplicar cantidad por precio los materiales y luego sacar el presupuesto general de los materiales

```
$conector =" SELECT nombre, descripcion, cantidad, precio, cantidad*precio FROM materiales";              
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$conector);
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){   
    $contador = 0;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>"; 
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";  
    echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";  
    echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";
    // echo $row[4];
    for ($i=0; $i < $row[4]; $i++) { 
        // echo $contador = $row[4];
        // var_dump($contador);
    }
}
```

Comment: La multiplicación que te devuelve la consulta si es la correcta

Comment: si ahora busco sumar todos esos datos para obtener el presupueso y es todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que `$row[4]` es tu valor de la multiplicación tu código quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
$conector =" SELECT nombre, descripcion, cantidad, precio, cantidad*precio FROM materiales";              
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$conector);
$contador = 0;
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row[0]</td>"; 
    echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";  
    echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";  
    echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
    echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";
    $contador = $contador + $row[4];
}
```

Terminando el `while` la variable `$contador` el valor del presupuesto y asi puedes hacer un `echo` en donde quieres que vaya.

Comment: gracias amigo, hice mas preguntas de como hacer un pdf por si fabes como  hacerlo me gustaria  tu ayuda porfa